# How can I extract the text from links on an HTML page in Perl?

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I am not an expert in Perl but I have written a Perl script to parse an HTML page and filter by all `href` tags:

The output are as shown below:

```
href="?Name">Name</a>
href="?Desc">Hourly Details</a>
href="/24x7/2012/11-November/">Data
href="./00:00:00/">00:00:00/</a>
href="./01:00:00/">01:00:00/</a>
href="./02:00:00/">02:00:00/</a>
href="./03:00:00/">03:00:00/</a>
href="./04:00:00/">04:00:00/</a>
href="./05:00:00/">05:00:00/</a>
href="./06:00:00/">06:00:00/</a>
href="./07:00:00/">07:00:00/</a>
href="./08:00:00/">08:00:00/</a>
href="./09:00:00/">09:00:00/</a>
href="./10:00:00/">10:00:00/</a>
href="./11:00:00/">11:00:00/</a>
href="./12:00:00/">12:00:00/</a>
href="./13:00:00/">13:00:00/</a>
href="./14:00:00/">14:00:00/</a>
href="./15:00:00/">15:00:00/</a>
href="./16:00:00/">16:00:00/</a>
href="./17:00:00/">17:00:00/</a>
href="./18:00:00/">18:00:00/</a>
href="./19:00:00/">19:00:00/</a>
href="./20:00:00/">20:00:00/</a>
href="./21:00:00/">21:00:00/</a>
href="./22:00:00/">22:00:00/</a>
href="./23:00:00/">23:00:00/</a>
```

Now I want to extract values within the href tags from "00:00:00" till "23:00:00" while exclude others. The result value would be added to string having a URL:

```
http://x.download.com/00:00:00
------URL------------/..href../
..............................
http://x.download.com/23:00:00
```

However by trying the below code:

```
foreach (@tag) {
    if (m/href/) {
        if ($_ =~ /"\/24/ && $_ =~ /"\/[0-9]/) {
            my $href  = $_;
            my $start = index($href, "\"");
            my $end   = rindex($href, "\"");
            my $link  = substr($href, $start + 1, $end - $start - 1);
            print "Follow: " . $url . $link . "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Follow: http://x.download.com/24x7/2012/11-November/
```

What should my regular expression be such that required objective can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done very simply with a regular expression, as shown in the program below. It looks for a string of digits or colons immediately following `>` (and so looks for the text contents of the element rather the `href` attribute value as yours does) and captures that string into `$1`.

But I would prefer to see the problem solved from start to finish using a proper HTML parser, such as 
[`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder)
or
[`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM).

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @tag = <DATA>;

foreach (@tag) {
  next unless />([\d:]+)/;
  print "http://x.download.com/$1\n";
}

__DATA__
href="?Name">Name</a>
href="?Desc">Hourly Details</a>
href="/24x7/2012/11-November/">Data
href="./00:00:00/">00:00:00/</a>
href="./01:00:00/">01:00:00/</a>
href="./02:00:00/">02:00:00/</a>
href="./03:00:00/">03:00:00/</a>
href="./04:00:00/">04:00:00/</a>
href="./05:00:00/">05:00:00/</a>
href="./06:00:00/">06:00:00/</a>
href="./07:00:00/">07:00:00/</a>
href="./08:00:00/">08:00:00/</a>
href="./09:00:00/">09:00:00/</a>
href="./10:00:00/">10:00:00/</a>
```

**output**

```
http://x.download.com/00:00:00
http://x.download.com/01:00:00
http://x.download.com/02:00:00
http://x.download.com/03:00:00
http://x.download.com/04:00:00
http://x.download.com/05:00:00
http://x.download.com/06:00:00
http://x.download.com/07:00:00
http://x.download.com/08:00:00
http://x.download.com/09:00:00
http://x.download.com/10:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry could you provide what I should use in case of <DATA> in while loop - I am getting errors in program. It would be helpful if you can use @tag variable as in my above example

Comment: I used `DATA` so that I could include sample data in the Perl source. I have modified my solution so that it reads the data into `@tag` before processing it, as you requested

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to do it with regular expressions. You need a proper HTML parser, and regexes cannot do the job.

How are you fetching the web page?  If you're using WWW::Mechanize, then extracting the links from the page that you have fetched is a single method call, because WWW::Mechanize does the HTML parsing for you.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( $url );

my @links = $mech->links();
for my $link ( @links ) {
    say $link->text, ' -> ', $link->url; # Show the text and the URL
}
```

You'll need to reformat as you see fit, but that gives you an idea.

Comment: I am using $browser->get( $url ); to get the web page and then  $contents = $response->content; my @breakup = split( ' ', $contents ); to get the page content

Comment: What is `$browser`?  What class are you using to do the `get`?

Comment: I am using LWP lib to get the web page. use LWP::Simple;my $browser; $browser->get( $url ); to get the web page and then  $contents = $response->content; my @breakup = split( ' ', $contents ); to get the page content

Comment: So it's easy to switch to Mechanize.  Mechanize is built on top of LWP.  Then you can use the code snippet above and your link extraction is handled for you, and you don't have to deal with parsing.  You still have access to the content directly with `$mech->content`, just like with your LWP::Simple object.

Comment: @Prakash, in addition to what Andy is saying here, you can filter the links with a capturing regex like so `say "http://x.download.com/$_" foreach map { $_->url =~ m/$regex/ } $mech->links;`

Comment: Better than that, @axeman, Mech's `find_all_links` method has that filtering built in: `my @downloadlinks = $mech->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/:00:00/ );`  You can filter on the text of the link, too.  See [the docs for find_link() and find_all_links()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#$mech-%3Efind_link%28_..._%29)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need to specify a regex which will capture military times to the second.

```
my $regex 
    = qr{  # curly brackets instead of slashes
           # so that we can use literal slashes in expression

    "   # a quote
    \.  # a literal dot
    /   # a forward slash
    (   # begin capture group

       (?:              # begin uncaptured sub-group
           [01] \d      # a '0' or '1' followed by a digit
       |   2    [0-3]   # a '2' followed by 0-3
       )                # end grouping
       (?:         # begin repetition grouping
         :         # a literal colon               
         [0-5] \d  # digits 0-5 followed by any digit
       ){2}        # exactly twice
     )  # end capture

     /  # a forward slash
     "  # close quote
}x; # <- x-option allows annotated regex
...
```

This is equivalent to the following regex:

```
my $regex = qr/"\.\/((?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2})\/"/;
```

If your minutes and seconds will only ever be '00:00', then the expression is even easier:

```
my $regex = qr{"\./((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):00:00)/"};
```

Then you can test *and* retrieve the value by making the match in a *list* context:

```
if ( my ( $link ) = m/$regex/ ) { 
    say "http://x.download.com/$link";
}
```

If the test does not match, `$link` will be undefined. If it does match, having declared it as a list (of one), the match operation will assign the first capture to the variable.

Comment: Thanks but I get final link as Follow: http://x.download.com./23:00:00/ - note an extra dot after http://x.download.com

Comment: @Prakash, I think that would be your extraction code, which I did not change, but in the next version I added extraction code of my one. It's better to specify what you wanted to skip over in a capturing regex.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the examples as provided. I do see the expected output as requested per the question